# How to capture nested JSON object values and group them based on specific condition in Jmeter

Tags: json, dynamic, jmeter, nested, post-processor

Response:

[
{
"rid": 2016,
"userid": "abcd",
"cid": "xyz", ,
"rname": "ijk",
"des": null,
"con": [{
"fname": "amnt_type",
"op": "eqto",
"vtype": "ENUM",
"values": [{
"v1": "I",
"v2": null,
},
],
}, {
"fname": "usd",
"op": "GT",
"vtype": "NUMERIC",
"values": [{
"v1": "100.00",
"v2": null
}
]
}, {
"fname": "bcd",
"op": "GT",
"vtype": "ENUM",
"values": [{
"v1": "101",
"v2": null
}, {
"v1": "102",
"v2": null
}, {
"v1": "678",
"v2": null
}, {
"v1": "832",
"v2": null
}

```
            ]
        }, {
            "fname": "bcd",
            "op": "GT",
            "vtype": "ENUM",
            "values": [{
                    "v1": "101",
                    "v2": null
                }, {
                    "v1": "678",
                    "v2": null
                }, {
                    "v1": "832",
                    "v2": null
                }

            ]
        }, {
            "fname": "pcd",
            "op": "EQ",
            "vtype": "ENUM",
            "values": [{
                    "v1": "ATM",
                    "v2": null
                }, {
                    "v1": "KLX",
                    "v2": null
                }, {
                    "v1": "MKH",
                    "v2": null
                }

            ]
        }
    ]
}, {
    "rid": 876,
    "userid": "abcd",
    "cid": "xyz", ,
    "rname": "Rule2",
    "des": null,
    "con": [{
            "fname": "amnt_type",
            "op": "GT",
            "vtype": "ENUM",
            "values": [{
                    "v1": "I",
                    "v2": null,
                },
            ],
        }, {
            "fname": "bcd",
            "op": "EQ",
            "vtype": "ENUM",
            "values": [{
                    "v1": "685",
                    "v2": null
                }, {
                    "v1": "657",
                    "v2": null
                },

            ]
        },
    ]
}, {
    "rid": 9875,
    "userid": "abcd",
    "cid": "xyz", ,
    "rname": "PQR",
    "des": null,
    "con": [{
            "fname": "amnt_type",
            "op": "GT",
            "vtype": "ENUM",
            "values": [{
                    "v1": "I",
                    "v2": null,
                },
            ],
        },
    ]
}
```

]

ExpectedOutput:

{ {
"rname": "ijk",
"rid": 2016,
"con": [{
"fname": "amnt_type",
"op": "eqto",
"vtype": "ENUM",
"value": [
"I"

```
            ],
        }, {
            "fname": "usd",
            "op": "GT",
            "vtype": "NUMERIC",
            "value": [
                "100.00"

            ]

        }, {
            "fname": "bcd",
            "op": "GT",
            "vtype": "ENUM",
            "value": [
                "101", "102", "678", "832"

            ]
        }, {
            "fname": "pcd",
            "op": "EQ",
            "vtype": "ENUM",
            "value": [
                "ATM", "KLX", "MKH"

            ]
        }
    ]
}, {
    "rid": 876,
    "rname": "Rule2",
    "con": [{
            "fname": "amnt_type",
            "op": "GT",
            "vtype": "ENUM",
            "value": ["I"

            ],
        }, {
            "fname": "bcd",
            "op": "EQ",
            "vtype": "ENUM",
            "value": [
                "685", "657"

            ]
        }
    ]
}, {
    "rid": 9875,
    "userid": "abcd",
    "cid": "xyz", ,
    "rname": "PQR",
    "des": null,
    "con": [{
            "fname": "amnt_type",
            "op": "GT",
            "vtype": "ENUM",
            "value": ["I"

            ],
        },
    ],
},
}
```

Basically we need to capture all values under the values section and keep only value1 and combine it to it one array.

I am able to get rid,rname,con together but not able to achieve the value parameter.

I tried using JSON extractor, regular expression extractor still not able to get the output in desired format. Please help.

I am using groovy and Jmeter 5.0

Answer (score 0):

If I correcltly got your requirement you could do something like:

```
def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())

response.each { entry ->
    entry.con.each { con ->
        def value = con.values.collect { value -> value.v1 }
        con.remove('values')
        con.put('value', value)
    }
}
vars.put('someVariable', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(response).toPrettyString())
```

Put the code to the [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) which needs to be a child of the Sampler which returns the original JSON

The generated JSON can be accessed as `${someVariable}` where required

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)
- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)

Comment: Thanks you for the response. I am facing No signature or method: org.apache.groovy.internal.LazyMap() is applicable for argument types (BigDecimal). Please suggest